# Android ScrollView keeps redrawing it's components endlessly

Tags: android, scrollview

I am out of options, maybe someone knows better. My problem is that I have a ScrollView (descentand) and insert a View (descendant) into it. Everything is fine, unless I want to scroll upwards (view goes up, finger goes down) until the origin of scroll area is reached, after that moment I can see MYView.onDraw() called every 130 ms approximately, and this goes forever.

I found out that this weird behaviour is caused by this code:

```
myScrollView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        Log.d("myapp", "onTouch");
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP 
            || event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) return true;
        return false;
    }
```

});

If I comment out the `if` statement, the problem is solved. I am not even sure what this line of code does. It think it supposed to disable the "slow-down" momentum effect. (Because for my application it is not desired). I think I copy-pasted this code from someone's sample, here on SO few month ago.

So the question is how to remove the "eternal loop of onDraws", and still keep the "no-slow-down effect" code.

Answer (score 0):

The meaning of the returned boolean value is documented as:

*True if the listener has consumed the event, false otherwise.*

Not really explaining. "Consumed" means that the other listeners do not need to see the event. "Not consumed" means that the listener may not see the subsequent related events.

It is not clear for me what the code was intended to do -- it definitely just consumes two types of events.
But you could add `event.getAction()` to the log and see what is going on. As I remember, different versions of Android may generate a bit different sequences of events for the same gesture.